# Chrome Console does not show object properties any more

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, browser

Recently i noticed that chrome does not show the properties of any object, it was showing them 10 days back. Then I checked same thing in IE, Firefox, they all do not show any property.

For example :

```
var a={};  
a   // gives Object {}
```

Some days back it showed all the properties in chrome at least.
What could be the possible reason behind this change.?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparantly, Chrome used to emulate the [dir](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/commandline-api#dirobject) function by default, but now it seems to emulate [inspect](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/commandline-api#inspectobject).

So to get a listing of all the properties of the specified object,

Instead of `a` which maps to `inspect(a)`, Use `dir(a);`